# saving frames from ffmpeg

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg in C# to discard a movie to its frame images and save each frame as a .png image. However, I can not save the frames! the code operates, but then I can not save them to a folder! I would like to know how can I save the output of ffmpeg to a folder.

```
public static void GetVideoFrames(string saveTo)
{
    string mpegpath = @"E:\Csharp\ffvideo\";
    string ffmpegPath = Path.Combine(mpegpath, "ffmpeg.exe");
    string inputMovie = @"E:\Csharp\ffvideo\test.mp4";
    string parameters = string.Format("ffmpeg -i {0} -f image2 frame-%1d.png -y {1}",
        inputMovie, saveTo);
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpegPath;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = parameters;
    proc.Start();
}
```

Comment: Right now when I run this code, I get this error: Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg' ffmpeg:Invalid argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `proc.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpegPath;`, but then your `parameters` string is

```
string.Format("ffmpeg -i {0} -f image2 frame-%1d.png -y {1}", inputMovie, saveTo);
```

Try taking the `ffmpeg` out of this string so it instead looks like:

```
string.Format("-i {0} -f image2 frame-%1d.png -y {1}", inputMovie, saveTo);
```

What I would suggest is happening here is that the command that is actually being executed is:

```
\path\to\ffmpeg.exe ffmpeg -i E:\Csharp\ffvideo\test.mp4 -f image2 frame-%1d.png -y \output\dir\path\
```

where the EXE is not liking that second `ffmpeg`.

**Edit:**

I was able to segment a video into individual images with the following command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i Test.mp4 -f image2 frame-1%d.png
```

The `-y` option actually indicates that `ffmpeg` will [overwrite the files without asking](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options).

From the [description](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Description)

> Anything found on the command line which cannot be interpreted as an option is considered to be an output filename.

Meaning that `ffmpeg` is treating `\output\dir\path\` as the output file, which won't work in your case.

I think your best bet might be to try setting `proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` to the 
directory you want the images written to. Note: the edit below is probably a better approach.

**Edit 2:**

To get them going in the chosen directory, change your format string from this:

```
frame-%1d.png
```

to this:

```
\output\path\frame-%1d.png
```

Comment: I did this, but the out put didn't change. It thinks that whatever comes ater -y is for the format, so it tells me that it can not find a suitable format for whatever that is after -y !

Comment: I will give this a try tonight and will let you know how it goes. thanks for helping out.